# Play Slick: Like with an Option[String] column

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

How can I make a query with a `like` when the object is a `column[Option[String]]`?

This is my model:

```
val id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
val ownerName: Rep[String] = column[String]("owner_name")
val membershipCode: Rep[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("membership_code")
```

And this is my query:

```
val query = orderTableQuery.filter { order =>
  Seq(
    search.filter(!_.isEmpty).map(filterString => {
      val searchTerm = s"%$filterString%".toLowerCase
      Seq(
//            Some(order.membershipCode.toLowerCase like searchTerm), // This is the one causing problems
        Some(order.ownerName.toLowerCase like searchTerm) // This works fine
      ).flatten.reduceLeftOption(_ || _).getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])
    }),
    // ...other optional filters
  ).flatten.reduceLeftOption(_ && _).getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])
}
```

However, when I try to remove the comment tags from that line, the type of the sequence changes, so i can not make the `reduceLeftOption(_ || _)` part, if I add a `get` inside the option column then it compile fine, but when i try the query slick throws an error because you can not use a get in the database (which for me makes sense), but then, how can I handle this `Option[String]` column?

**Edit**

I have tried some things, like:

1. Compile fine, but in execution throws exception in the get

   Some(order.membershipCode.get.toLowerCase.like(searchTerm))
2. The `reduceLeftOption(_ || _)` does not work anymore

   Some(order.membershipCode.toLowerCase.like(searchTerm))
3. Type mismatch

   Some(order.membershipCode.toLowerCase.like(Some(searchTerm)))

**Edit 2**

Now this is fixed, more info in https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1664

Comment: Can you try `Some(order.membershipCode.toLowerCase like Some(searchTerm))`?

Comment: The like method does not accept an Some(String), only string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `asColumnOf` to achieve this:

`order.membershipCode.asColumnOf[String].toLowerCase like searchTerm`

Depending on your database, this will produce a query that contains a `WHERE` clause that looks something like this:

`where lcase(cast("membershipCode" as VARCHAR)) like ...etc`

Slick [issue 1664](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1664) is a ticket looking for a general solution to this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i hope there is a way, is hard to believe that is so counter intuitive to make a simple "columnNullable like 'text'", i will be cheking the issue